# How to pass directory path as argument to batch file

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm writing a pipeline script to call a batch file, which in turn will call a .wsf script.

I am trying to execute a batch file with one parameter. The parameter is a file path. I can get the Jenkins script to execute the batch file, but I cannot successfully pass the file path as an argument.

The .wsf script  (which uses VBScript) builds out the full file path using the input directory. It uses backslashes, so I'm assuming that the path I pass to the batch file should be defined using backslashes.

I have tried many different suggested syntax, but nothing works. The script either won't run due to syntax error, or it just passes the variable name as literal string instead of the assigned value that I expected.

The name of the actual .bat file does have an ampersand in it, so I named this example similarly.

This is what I currently tried:

```
    environment {
        ROOT_DIR = 'http:\\\\myserver.mycity.mycompany.com\\svn\\PRODUCT\\trunk'
    }
...
        stage('Copy my files') {
            steps {
                bat script: "ABC_123\\Rock^&Roll42.bat", args: "\"${env.ROOT_DIR }\""
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script), the `args` argument does not exist, so you may want to try:

```
bat script: "ABC_123\\Rock^&Roll42.bat ${env.ROOT_DIR}"
```

As another option, when a variable is defined inside the `environment` block it will not only be available inside the pipeline by using `env.ROOT_DIR` but it will also be created as an environment variable inside the shells that you use.
So it can be accessed directly in the cmd/powershell/sh shell by (depending on the shell syntax) using the variable as a normal shell variable, some examples:

1. `cmd` can use environment variables by appending `%` at the end and the start of the variable name, so it would be `%ROOT_DIR%`.
2. `sh` can use environment variables by using `$` so it would be `$ROOT_DIR`.

So, I would try this:

```
bat script: "ABC_123\\Rock^&Roll42.bat %ROOT_DIR%"
```

In the above example, the variable substitution is not happening on Groovy, it is being done directly by the shell you are executing. This is recommended for passing secrets to shell steps.